# small problem in cite for bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, bibliographystyle

why, for example in n.3, I don't get the publisher={Pafnuty Publications, Oxford},

```
@misc{driscoll2014chebfun,
  title={Chebfun guide},
  author={Driscoll, Tobin A and Hale, Nicholas and Trefethen, Lloyd N},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Pafnuty Publications, Oxford}
}
```

[image]

Same prooblem in 17,

```
@misc{whitefluid,
  title={Fluid mechanics', 2nd edn; 1986},
  author={White, FM},
  publisher={Singapore, McGraw-Hill Book Co}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example. 
https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: The entry `whitefluid` should probably be a `@book`. `1986` should go into the `year` or `date` field. `2nd edn` should be turned into `edition = {2},` and `publisher={Singapore, McGraw-Hill Book Co}` should become `publisher={McGraw-Hill}, location = {Singapore},`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `@misc` bibliography type does not provide a `publisher` field. Use `organization` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{driscoll2014chebfun,
 title={Chebfun guide},
 author={Driscoll, Tobin A and Hale, Nicholas and Trefethen, Lloyd N},
 year={2014},
 organization={Pafnuty Publications, Oxford},
}\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more correct way to get the location is this:

```
 organization={Pafnuty Publications},
 location = {Oxford},
```

which gives:

[image]